# Selenium+PHPUnit: Set maximum waiting time in waitForElementPresent

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I use Selenium and PHPUnit. In my testcases, I use

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase::waitForElementPresent($xpath);
```

to wait for some time until element specified by `$xpath` becomes present. Is there any way to change the maximum time of waiting?

Comment: what do you mean by maximum time?You have to specify a limited time for waiting.

Comment: Well I don't specify it so some default value is used. I would like to change it but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waitForElementPresent()` takes *two* arguments. The first one is the *locator* and the other is **Timeout in miliseconds**.

Example :

```
waitForElementPresent("Your xpath","80000").
```

This will wait for the given xpath for 80 seconds.